# Partial view(s) ‘Enum.cshtml’ implementation works nice while excluded from the project (while included it generates compilation error)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there anybody out there how can explain why the ‘enum implementation’ as suggested in article [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776908/Dealing-with-Enum-in-MVC] works while both partial views of Enum.cshtml are NOT a part (excluded!) of the project?

Explanation

Currently, I am using MVC 5.2.1 to set up a new project. In this project, as many others, I have to use enumerations, more precisely, fancied ones with Display attributes. In this current version, luckily, we do not have to add enum helpers (as I was doing according K. Scott Allen’s’ tutorial ‘ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamental’ (chapter Entity Framework 6, clip Scaffolding, free assessable) [https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals&author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m6-ef6&clip=4] on PluralSight. 
Using fancied enumerations, out-of-the-box pops, with this version of MVC, on several Create views the EditorFor extension has been exchanged with the new EnumDropDownList extension. So far, so good!
On this particular part no extension method such as an EnumHelper has to be set anymore, nice. 
However…, due to what several others members already mentioned, having some trouble displaying those fancied enumerations on an Index – or Edit view, I took their tips for granted and followed this post on Code Project [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776908/Dealing-with-Enum-in-MVC] right away. Comparing what I have learned in K. Scot Allen’s clip and what has been posted by Shahriar Hossain, it turned out that both directions did NOT work. Following the clip of Scot Allen, his manually configured EnumHelper isn’t touched programmatically, on the other hand following Shahriar post, it gave errors like not able to find the enum.cshtml during compile time.
From a chronologically point of view, my ‘water’ is telling me that the tips of Shahriar must work one way or the other, so … something else apparently is ‘not in sinc’.

Solution (work-around type)

Finally, I figured out (however, what I essentially hate is reaching some goals simply through trial-error, not really knowing what I’m doing) that I had to EXCLUDE both partial views from the project (in both template folder; the DisplayTemplates- as well as the EditorTemplates one) to get it working.

[image]

So, the implementation of partial view(s) ‘Enum.cshtml’ works nice while excluded from the project (however included it generates a compilation error). May be this trial-error tip helps others facing comparable trouble.

Is there anybody out there how can explain why the ‘enum implementation’ as suggested works while both partial views of Enum.cshtml are NOT a part (excluded!) of the project.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to clean your project...Open you project con VS and then right Click on it. Then choose 'Clean'.

Comment: This seems very unlikely, as far as I know the `RazorViewEngine` finds templates at runtime. It doesn't use the project file.

Comment: For sure I cleaned several times, however I perform cleaning a bit different (standard) way: Build (menu) > Clean: checking output. I seems to me very unlikely that there is a difference between @Hackerman steps and what I'm used to practise. Well, it's only working when the Enum.cshtml's are both EXcluded from the project, I can't help, I can't make 'france fries' out of it!

Comment: Lets say that your projects name is `MyAwesomeWebSite`. Now in your `bin` folder locate `MyAwesomeWebSite.dll` and delete it...now rebuild your project.

Comment: And yess... I thruly believe in Chile do live high-level professionals too!

Comment: I just performed your suggestion, thx anyway! The latest time stamp was from minutes ago. I cleaned again... Rebuild the whole thing... Guess what? Still... it only works with the partials EXcluded.